# Как добавить несколько option в select2?

Tags: jquery, select, select2

Я делаю запрос к контроллеру .net mvc и получаю json

```
{
"name": "pic.png",
"name": "pic2.png"
}
```

Затем, я пытаюсь добавить эти значения в уже созданный select2, но появляется только 1 опция и она сразу же выбирается. Я не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
let options = [];
... axios.get...
options.push(new Option(response.name, '', false, false));
... after axios finish ... 
$(select2JQobject).append(options).trigger('change');
```

Comment: А зачем такой объект с одинаковыми ключами?

Comment: При одинаковых ключах объект будет возвращать последнее значение по этому ключу. Вам бы сразу массив передавать, и его уже перебирать.

Comment: @PavelNazarian Это никак не решает проблему, bootstrap5, новейший select2. Есть id - нету id - не играет роли, в select2 все равно появляется только 1 опция. а в самом объекте html select создаются все опции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вторым параметром попробуйте передать значение, у вас пустая строка там, вот пример:

```
var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

Comment: Это никак не решает проблему, bootstrap5, новейший select2. Есть id - нету id - не играет роли, в select2 все равно появляется только 1 опция. а в самом объекте html select создаются все опции